# How to use data from an ajax.done to stop a while loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a while loop that does an ajax request to the backend and I want to use data from the backend response to decide when to get out of the while loop. Something like in the code below. The code below doesn’t work because the breakout variable is not accessible outside the request.done method. So I tried to update an html tag from inside the request.done method then try to use this tag to break out of the while loop but this did not work either.

```
while(true) { 
  request = $.ajax({
    ‘url’:’some url’,
    ‘Method’:’GET’
  });
  request.done(fuction(data) { 
    var this_value = data['break']
    if(this_value = "name") { 
      break;
    }
  });
```

Comment: The "code below" doesn't work because ajax requests are asynchronous, so you just have essentially `while (true) { ; }` - javascript is **single threaded** so your ajax callbacks can't be called-back while your code is running.  So you have to `break` out of the `while` *before* you know whether to break out or not.   In summary: don't use a `while` - start a new request from the `.done` if you want them continuous, or use a better suited technology such as websockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code below doesn’t work because the breakout variable is not accessible outside the `request.done` method.

No, that is not the reason. The reason is that:

- The `done` callback never executes, because the engine is forever busy running the `while` loop, not ever processing the event queue, where the event is sitting that would instruct the engine to call the `done` callback. This also explains why your other attempt with the HTML element didn't help.
- `break` is invalid where you have it, because it occurs in a function where there is no loop to break from.
- The code has several other syntax errors.

You would need to deal with the asynchronous nature of the `done` callback. It can only execute when the `while` loop ends, and so you should have no `while (true)` to begin with.

Here is how it could work:

```js
let url = "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new";

function loop() {
  let request = $.ajax({
    url,
    Method: 'GET'
  });
  request.done(function (data) { 
    console.log(data);
    if (data == 10) return; // break condition
    loop(); // repeat
  });
}

loop();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In more modern JavaScript, you'd use the `fetch` API and `async`/`await`, and then you *can* use `while` again, simply because `await` suspends the function execution context:

```js
let url = "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new";

(async function () {
  while (true) {
    let request = await fetch(url);
    let data = await request.json();
    console.log(data);
    if (data == 10) break; // break condition
  }
})();
```